# How to edit sda1 file from Ubuntu live CD

Tags: live-cd

The file is `/etc/inittab` and the sda1 partition has been mounted. However, when I open the file in a text editor it is in read-only format.

How do I make it writable from my Ubuntu 10 live CD?

Answer (score 4):

The file `/etc/inittab` can only be edited by *root*.

To edit this file from a "normal" user account with a console based editor like `nano` use:

```
sudo nano /etc/inittab
```

Comment: Hi, so do i need to be logged in as root? how do I do that from a livecd?

Comment: @user139646 see updated answer

Comment: The LiveCD user is an password-less admin in the system, you just need to use `sudo` to elevate the commands you normally use and be able to edit the file.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with nano unfortunately, is there any simple editor that could work?

Comment: `joe`, `emacs -nw`, `vim`, `ed` :-), ...

Comment: Unless there's something seriously weird about `etc/inittab` that I don't know about, you should be able to use any plaintext editor, like `gedit` or `kate`...

Comment: @Ernir: But not with `sudo` - than he has to use `gksudo`.